# self-signed applet without popups

Tags: java, applet, certificate, digital-certificate

I have a self signed applet running in our intranet. We want to achieve that the browser would not ask for any confirmation before allowing the applet ro run.

I tried to add our certificate to the java's cacerts file with no success.

keytool -alias myCACert -import -keystore C:\dev\jdk-8u51-windows-x64\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file myCACert.cer

Also adding the certs using java control panel doesn't work as well.

Am I missing something or it is not going to work at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to go to Control Panel -> Java Control Panel -> Advanced -> Secure Execution Environment and select there appropriate options?

Comment: I am using java 8u51 and i do not have such an option. BTW i have managed to get it working by removing chanined certificates and importing the certificate to the cacerts like i did before.

Comment: So, no problem now? You can add your solution as an answer and accept it. It will help other users who have same problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry I have not used stackoverflow before. I'll to it tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working by removing chanined certificates and importing the certificate to the JRE's cacerts file.